# Get DB2 database name using SQL

Tags: db2, metadata, db2-luw

Is it possible to find the database name of a DB2 database by querying the catalog metadata? For instance, we can find the columns of tables using `SELECT tbname, column_name FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS`. Is there an analogous query that can get the database name?

I need this because I am running a query to get the remaining free space in the DB, across several instances. I would prefer to have the query itself tell me the name of the database.

Let's say my JDBC URL is `jdbc:db2://hostname.company.com:portNumber/InstanceName`. I need the InstanceName.

Running DB2 10.5 on Linux.

Comment: so, you need instance name before you're connected to db, so who will execute such sql query?

Comment: I know what the instance name is. I connect to the DB and run a certain query, which returns available space. I do this for several DB2 instances. I would prefer to run a query that returns "For database DB_NAME, the available space is NNN Gb". Right now, I only get the "NNN Gb" returned from the query. If I need to put all this data together, I need to add the DB name myself. To automate as much as possible/reduce confusion, would prefer to get this directly from the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:  `values current server`  (for DB2 on Linux Unix Windows) , it returns the database name to which you are currently connected. Or `select current server from sysibm.sysdummy1` if you insist on using the catalog.